# How can I speed up my code finding the parameter which yields zero determinant for increasingly larger matrices?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I build a square matrix with matrix elements dependent on the parameter `x`. I need to find all values of `x` within a reasonable range (say `-10<x<10`) such that the determinant of this matrix is `0`. My method takes far too long for larger matrices.

First, the matrix elements are built from the numerical eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a previous matrix as follows:

```
(* In what follows a, b and c are numeric - example values could be a=0.5, b=0.5 and c=-0.2*)

eigens[a_, b_] := eigens[a, b] = 
   Block[{},
    m = 10; 
    ham = Table[i^2*KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, -m, m},{j, -m, m}] + 
          Table[a*KroneckerDelta[i, j + 1], {i, -m, m}, {j, -m, m}] + 
          Table[a*KroneckerDelta[i, j - 1], {i, -m, m}, {j, -m, m}] + 
          Table[b*KroneckerDelta[i, j + 2], {i, -m, m}, {j, -m, m}] + 
          Table[b*KroneckerDelta[i, j - 2], {i, -m, m}, {j, -m, m}]; 

    SortBy[Transpose[Eigensystem[ham, Method -> "Banded"]], First]
] (* Eigenvalues and functions later used in calculating matrix elements *)

val1[a_, b_, n_] := val1[a, b, n] = eigens[a, b][[n + 1]][[1]] (* Eigenvalues *)
func1[a_, b_, n_] := func1[a, b, n] = Chop[(1./Sqrt[N[2*Pi]])*eigens[a, b][[n + 1]][[2]]].Table[Exp[I*j*\[CurlyPhi]], {j, -m, m}]; (* Sum of exponentials where coefficients come from the eigenvector *)
val2[a_, b_, n_] := val2[a, b, n] = val1[-a, -b, n] (* Defined as eigenvalues for negative a and b *)
func2[a_, b_, n_] := func2[a, b, n] = func1[-a, -b, n] (* Same but for the function *)
```

My matrix elements are then calculated using `val1`, `val2`, `func1`, and `func2` via the following:

```
me[(a_)?NumericQ, (b_)?NumericQ, c_, x_, k_, l_, p_, q_] := Block[{}, 
    prefactor = (-2*Pi*c)/(val1[a, b, p] + val2[a, b, q] - x); 
    numInt = NIntegrate[
                 Chop[func1[a, b, p]*func2[a, b, q]*Conjugate[func1[a, b, k]]*Conjugate[func2[a, b, l]]],
        {\[CurlyPhi], -Pi, Pi}, 
        AccuracyGoal -> 10,
        Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule","SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}
        ];

    prefactor*numInt
]//Chop;
```

***Is there a better way of performing this numerical integral?***

Finally I build my square matrix of size `(max+1)^2` via:

```
matrix[a_, b_, c_, x_, max_] := Block[{}, 
    g = Table[me[a, b, c, x, i, f, j, k], {i, 0, max},{f, 0, max}, {j, 0, max}, {k, 0, max}]; 

    h = Rationalize[ArrayReshape[g, {(max + 1)^2, (max + 1)^2}]-IdentityMatrix[(max + 1)^2], 0]
];
```

and I find the values of `x` (and sort them in ascending order) such that the determinant is `0` using Reduce:

```
findParameter[a_, b_, c_, max_] := findParameter[a, b, c, max] =
    Sort[N[Reduce[Det[matrix[a, b, c, x, max]] == 0. && -10 <= x <= 10, x, Reals]]]
```

***Is there a more efficient way than using Reduce?***

My problem is that for larger and larger matrices this method takes way *way* too long. For example while `findParameter` takes 0.4s for `max=2`, it rapidly scales up and when `max=4`, `findParameter` takes 30s . Ideally I would like to evaluate this problem for `max=6` quickly, as further calculations currently seems to be taking hours/days!

Comment: Is there a way to go from an answer in n dimensions to an answer in n+1 dimensions? If so, this might allow you to leverage previous answers.

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, `c` meant to stay symbolic all the time? Then there is probably no chance to get it working in reasonable time. Otherwise, please provide typically values for `a`, `b`, and `c`. Guessing parameters is a pain in the neck.

Comment: Moreover, it might help little to use `ham = SparseArray[
  {
   Band[{1, 1}] -> Range[-N[m], N[m], 1]^2,
   Band[{1, 2}] -> N[a],
   Band[{2, 1}] -> N[a],
   Band[{1, 3}] -> N[b],
   Band[{3, 1}] -> N[b]
   },
  {2 m + 1, 2 m + 1}, 0.
  ]` for generating the matrices.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher `a`, `b`, and `c` are always numeric and something like between 0 and 1 (and `c` is negative). An example would be `a=0.5`, `b=0.5`, and `c=-0.2` - I'll edit the question appropriately thanks.